# Lost dual boot on Windows update

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I was careless and just clicked all HP updates in Windows 10 (>1GB) for my Pavillion x360 and went for a walk. Now that I come back I have lost dual boot.

The Ubuntu partitions are still there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AeM1.png I assume E=swap, F=root, G=home

The computer previously booted Ubuntu  16.04 and Windows 10.

I looked in the UEFI and pressed enter for the Ubuntu alternative. But still only Windows boot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/35cPn.jpg

Please tell how I can get dual boot back.

Thank you

Comment: Try Boot Repair Disk https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Thank you. I am downloading it now. It will take me a little time. I have to learn how to put it on USB. My laptop does not have an optical unit.

Comment: I still have the installation USB. Would it be possible to "reinstall Ubuntu without formatting any partitions?"

Comment: I am just using unebootin for the first time and it will not find the USB flash disk I inserted.

Comment: Could never make unetbootin find my flash disk in another Ubuntu machine. Instead I put boot_repair_cd on USB using Rufus under Windows. It is a one click program - "fix boot" and it really fixed my boot problem. Boot menu became a little cluttered though, will have to look into that later. http://i.imgur.com/G6ia31v.jpg But alternatives 1 and 3 work fine. Many thanks to member nobody, very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It is my experience that Windows updates knock out the dual boot process.  How exactly, I don't know.  I fix it either by reinstalling Ubuntu (there is an option that repairs and saves your files) or; with USB bootable stick and recovery mode.  In recovery mode, various options will clean & repair the grub entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem. When it happens, I go to BIOS and change the Boot order, then reinstall grub.

Here is the answer I use (I have it bookmarked):
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: "*This is a very common problem*" and yet in 2021.04 we still have to resort to all kind of tricks to re-enable Ubuntu after a Windows  update. The Ubuntu install USB has "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". It should also have "Repair boot".

Comment: You have a good point. I'd rather have my pc come without pre-installed Windows and (more absurdly) deleting windows wouldn't break my warranty. Has nothing to do with the components. Would decrease the cost of the PC, and decrease the number of people using dual boot.